# Is it possible to share a session between web and iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, authorization, appauth

I'm using AppAuth in my iOS app for Authorization. Specifically i'm using the Authorization Code flow.

Now with help of URL schema, I will open up iOS app when user clicks on a certain link on the web application. Ideally I would like to authenticate the user automatically from web to the iOS app after the user clicks on the link.

Is this possible?

The current Authorization Flow uses `OIDExternalUserAgentSession`

Comment: You can do it by passing parameters which can help you to determine the user identity

Comment: Can you elaborate this @Ammar. Wouldn't that be a security risk?

Comment: You can prevent danger
Suppose you have a specific link will pass the Hash within this link and then Hash process it within the application (in a unique way can not be imitated) so that can not understand this hashtags only by the server then determines the identity of the user and no one can do this process only your application